# How to assign Pointer to an Array, to a new Array?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I got this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
int a[3]={1,2,3},
    b[3];
int (*p)[3]= &a;

b = p;

for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    printf("%i",b[i]);
}
```

-I wanted output to be like "123", but I am having problems assigning the b array to what the p is pointing.

ps -
`memcpy( b, p, sizeof(b));` does just what i want but i want to do it without the use of that function.

Comment: This declaration `int (*p)[3]= &a` is misleading at best, and it almost certainly doesn't work the way you want it to.

Comment: What is wrong with "that function"?

Comment: @ScottHunter: Presumably the OP doesn't want a copy of the array.

Comment: How about just a pointer to the array?

Comment: Yes.  `int* p = a;` ...   `b` can be declared the same way.  `int* b = p;` or `int* b = a`.  If you want a pointer to somewhere other than the beginning of the array, it is, for example `int* p = &a[1];`  for a pointer to the second element in the array.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Not if "`memcpy...` does just what I want" is to be believed.

Comment: If you want a copy of the array, and not just another pointer to the array, you either have to use `memcpy` or loop through the array elements and assign each element to a position in the new array.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Lundin I was trying to assign array b to array a with the help of a pointer to a, but as said in the forum, arrays cant be assigned like a normal operator is, I thought there was a way around that and that's why I posted this question in the first place.

Comment: The normal way is to use memcpy. Everything else is obfuscation and might result in slower code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
b = p;
```

has a couple of problems.  First of all, array expressions may not be the target of the `=` operator; you can't assign an entire array in a single operation like that<sup>1</sup>.

Secondly, the types don't match; `p` has type `int (*)[3]`, while `b` has type `int [3]`.  Arrays are not pointers - array *expressions* "decay" to pointer expressions under most circumstances, but in this case even the pointers would be of incompatible types (`b` would decay to an expression of type `int *`, not `int (*)[3]`).

No, the only ways to copy the contents of one array to the other are to use library functions like `memcpy` or to use a loop to assign each element individually:

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
  b[i] = (*p)[i]; // or b[i] = a[i]
```

That's it.

---

1. Initialization is different from assignment.

Answer (score 0):

*"...but i want to do it without the use of `[memcpy(,,)]`."*

It is unclear why using `memcpy()` is not agreeable in this exercise, but it does do the task more efficiently then loop for large array sizes.

If you just want a pointer to the array...

```
int a[3] = {1,2,3};
//create pointer
int *b = a;//does not copy array a, just points to it   

//If an additional array is needed, do this...
int b[3] = {0};
int i = 0;

//to copy, without memcpy(), use this alternative.
for(i=0; i<3; i++) b[i] = a[i];//makes copy of array a

for(i=0;i<3;i++)
   printf("%i", b[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays do not have the assignment operator. You need somehow to copy elements of one array to another array.

Without using the standard function `memcpy` you can use an ordinary loop as for example

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ); i++ )
{
    b[i] = a[i];
}
```

Or if to use intermediate pointers you can write

```
for ( int *p = a, *q = b; p != a + sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ); ++p )
{
    *q++ = *p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a small fixed size array, perfectly suitable for wrapping inside a struct, so you can do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct ia3 {
    int data[3];
}

int main(void)
{
    struct ia3 a = {{1,2,3}};
    struct ia3 b;
    struct ia3 *p = &a;
    
    b = *p; // struct assignment
    
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
        printf("%i",b.data[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just a wrapper around memcpy though...

Comment: @Lundin Does the standard really define struct assignment in terms of `memcpy` function? If not, then this code does not use `memcpy` as C code (which is what is being asked).

Comment: Not explicitly, as far as I know. Though assignment has the same rules as memcpy (no overlap): "If the value being stored in an object is read from another object that overlaps in any way the storage of the first object, then the overlap shall be exact and the two objects shall have qualified or unqualified versions of a compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: As for just fulfilling artificial requirements for the heck of, we could also do `#define memcopy memcpy`...

Comment: @Lundin The reason for the requirement is not known, but the question itself is clear enough. To me it sounds the asker simply wants a nice syntax, or more type safety than what is provided by `memcpy`, or maybe to learn how to do "array assignment" in C without using raw memory copying. All seem perfectly legit motivations for a SO question to me (but I'm sure there are many who disagree).